# Choose randomly values in a column separated by ","?

Tags: r

It's my first time asking a question here, and as a French person with a terrible level in English, I will try to be as clear as possible.

I have a PBDB dataframe called PBDBcambrian2 in R with one of its columns bothering me. I have already made diversity calculations by removing all its uncertain occurrences, but now I would like to keep them but randomly select a single stage among these cells for each genre.

For example, if my dataframe look like this :

```
Genus_revised             Stage
Cambraster        Stage4,Wuliuan,Drumian        
Cambraster               Wulian    
Cymbionites           Stage4,Wuliuan      
Sokkaejaecystis    Guzhangian,Paibian,Jiangshanian
```

And I want that randomly, there is only one stage by genre (it’s an example below)

```
Genus_revised            Stage
Cambraster              Drumian        
Cambraster               Wulian    
Cymbionites              Wuliuan      
Sokkaejaecystis        Jiangshanian
```

Is there a way, for all of this column, to randomly choose between the stages separated by ","?

I’m totally stuck because it’s something I’ve never had to handle, so thanks to those who will help me!

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that splits the string vector by commas and then samples one element only.

```r
df1 <-
  structure(list(
    Genus_revised = c("Cambraster", "Cambraster", "Cymbionites", "Sokkaejaecystis"), 
    Stage = c("Stage4,Wuliuan,Drumian", "Wulian", "Stage4,Wuliuan", 
              "Guzhangian,Paibian,Jiangshanian")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))


rndstage <- function(x) {
  strsplit(x, ",") |> sapply(sample, size = 1L)
}

set.seed(2024)
rndstage(df1$Stage)
#> [1] "Wuliuan"      "Wulian"       "Stage4"       "Jiangshanian"

df2 <- data.frame(Genus_revised = df1$Genus_revised)
set.seed(2024)
df2$Stage <- rndstage(df1$Stage)
df2
#>     Genus_revised        Stage
#> 1      Cambraster      Wuliuan
#> 2      Cambraster       Wulian
#> 3     Cymbionites       Stage4
#> 4 Sokkaejaecystis Jiangshanian
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-14 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try this `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  # create a row counter:
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  # split `Stage` by comma (no need to specify `sep = ","`):
  separate_rows(Stage) %>%
  # for each distinct `rowid`...
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  # ...take 1 random sample:
  sample_n(1)
```

Data (thanks to Rui Barradas):

```
df1 <-
  structure(list(
    Genus_revised = c("Cambraster", "Cambraster", "Cymbionites", "Sokkaejaecystis"), 
    Stage = c("Stage4,Wuliuan,Drumian", "Wulian", "Stage4,Wuliuan", 
              "Guzhangian,Paibian,Jiangshanian")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```